# CakePHP save a three-model relationship association

Tags: cakephp, save

I have the following output which I need to be inserted in the database:

```
Array
(
[Test] => Array
    (
    )

[Question] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [category_id] => 3
                [answer_style_id] => 2
                [Answer] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [capital_category_id] => 14
                                [correct] => 1
                            )

                       ...
         ...
```

Briefly, each Test hasMany Questions, and each Question hasMany Answer, with each associated model having a foreign key which need to be set by Cake (each Question has a test_id, and each Answer has a question_id).

The problem is that when I `$this->Test->saveAll($data);`, only the Test and the Questions get saved, not the answers.

How can I save all data, with Cake automagically setting the foreign key for each associated model?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can save deep model trees since CakePHP 2.1 this way

```
$this->SomeModel->saveAll($data, array('deep' => true));
```

Reference here > http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/new-features-in-cakephp-2-1.html#model-saveall-model-saveassociated-model-validateassociated

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Glad this has been fixed :)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure but I think it's impossible to save third level relation.

from Cakephp:

> Saving related data with saveAll()
>   will only work for directly associated
>   models.

you'll have to retrieve third level data and save it apart from them.

Comment: saveAll() will do either 1) multi rows of the same model 2) a main model and all its direct relations. the 3rd row will have to be done manually.

Comment: Oh...this isn't the answer I was hoping. So, I will have to do this manually. I thought it was a more caky approach to save an n number of model relationship levels. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have three models A, B and C

A hasMany B
B hasMany C

$A->saveAll() will save model A & B but not C

Here is a playaround I use:

in model B override afterSave like this

```
function afterSave($created) {
    if ($created) { // check if we are in save not update
        $this->data['B']['id'] = $this->id;
        $this->data['C'] = $this->data['B']['C'];
        $this->saveAll($this->data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, looks like a good workaround, but since CakePHP 2.1, you can save models how deep you want, no matter level or recursion.