# How should data be formatted in CakePHP to save three levels of associations with saveAll()?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, has-many, save

I'm trying to build an "Add an Event" page.  You can add multiple "Schedules" - each of which will have calculations run on the date(s) / repeat options you set to create "Dates".

```
-Event hasMany Schedule
-Schedule hasMany Date
-Schedule belongsTo Event
-Date belongsTo Schedule
```

The question is - how does the data need to be formatted and/or how to the field names need to read in order to be able to saveAll() the data so Date(s) are also saved.  I have it currently working so it saves the Event and the Schedule... but I can't get it to also save the Date(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, since CakePHP 2.1, you can do it with saveAll(). Doesn't matter the deep level you have within your models. Here you can see the new features.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/new-features-in-cakephp-2-1.html#model-saveall-model-saveassociated-model-validateassociated

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE: See answer marked as 'answer'.  This answer is out of date.**

---

It appears it's not possible according to this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591044/cakephp-save-a-three-model-relationship-association).

ie - have to do it manually, not in the same "saveAll()".

Answer (score 1):

`saveAll` only works on models that are directly associated. From the CakePHP doc:

> Saving related data with saveAll() will only work for directly associated models. If successful, last_insert_id()'s will be stored in the related models id field, i.e. $this->RelatedModel->id.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data